# Xamarin: ImageButton not invoking command from style setter

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, binding

I am trying to create a custom navigation/"back" button in my mobile app. I want to bind the command as a setter property in a custom style and then apply that style to the ImageButton element in a larger custom element called HeaderNavigation.

Everything builds so that I can see my ImageButton with its styles applied. I can also see the command applied to the ImageButton when I watch its styles **but**, if I click on the ImageButton, the command is not called.

I've played around with the binding a little bit because I'm assuming that's the issue but no dice yet so I'm worried what I'm attempting isn't possible or maybe there's something stupid I'm missing.

Even if someone could just give me some debugging tips for mobile bindings, that would be helpful.

Thanks!

Code below:

**app.xaml**

```
<Style x:Key="NavButton" TargetType="ImageButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource IconButton}">
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="back.png"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="EndAndExpand"/>
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:App}},Path=BindingContext.OnBackButtonPressed}"/>
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Background}"/>
</Style>
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public async void OnBackButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // I do not get called :(
        _ = await Navigation.PopAsync();
}
```

**HeaderNavigation.cs**

```
public class HeaderNavigation : StackLayout
{
    private ImageButton _returnButton;

        public HeaderNavigation()
        {
            _returnButton = new ImageButton();

            _returnButton.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["NavButton"];

            Children.Add(_returnButton);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that your goal is to have the back button in your custom `NavigationHeader` call the `OnBackButtonPressed` method in your `App` class:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public async void OnBackButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This pop up will be the test.
        await MainPage.DisplayAlert("Message from button", "It worked", "OK");
    }
}
```

An approach that I've tested [Download from GitHub](https://github.com/IVSoftware/custom_back_button.git) to achieve the outcome you want factors in the likelihood that your custom `NavigationHeader` is going to be consumed in a view of some kind (e.g. `ContentPage`).

Try making this change in your Style declaration:

```
<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding BackButtonPressedCommand}" />
```

This way, when you consume your custom NavigationHeader e.g. in your `MainPage.xaml` ...

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:custom_back_button="clr-namespace:custom_back_button"
         x:Class="custom_back_button.MainPage">

<StackLayout>
    <custom_back_button:HeaderNavigation  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
</StackLayout>
```

...the bound command will be invoked in the context of the MainPage. (Likewise, if you consume it on some *other* page it will soak up the BindingContext of *that* page.)

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        BindingContext = new MainPageBinding();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The `ICommand` is resolved in the `BindingContext` resulting in a call to the `OnBackButtonPressed` in *this* class. Now use `((App)Application.Current)` to pass the action along to the `App` class as shown.

```
class MainPageBinding
{
    public MainPageBinding()
    {
        BackButtonPressedCommand = new Command(OnBackButtonPressed);
    }

    public ICommand BackButtonPressedCommand { get; private set; }
    private void OnBackButtonPressed(object o)
    {
        ((App)Application.Current).OnBackButtonPressed(o, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Pressing the back button shows a successful call to the popup coded in `App.OnBackButtonPressed`.

[image]

Comment: I ended up re-doing my logic a little bit but generally followed your advice here. Thanks to @ToolmakerSteve for pointing out that I wasn't using an actual command!

Comment: Glad to hear you got things working! You mention that you reworked the logic a little. Now I'm curious; Did the `ICommand` stay with the `Style`? I didn't want to cloud the issue before but did wonder, since you're making a custom back button in the first place and it seems to ultimately call the same method in the end regardless, why not just hard-wire the `Button.Click` event in the code behind class to call `OnBackButtonPressed`?

Comment: It was odd-- you could see it passed into the style but the binding never actually applied to the command. 

I wanted to keep all of my navigation logic as commands and keep them together so I was choosing that over hard-wiring the event.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. That method isn't a command. Property `Command` needs to be bound to a `Command`.
   in App.xaml.cs:

```cs
public Command BackButtonCommand { get; } = new Command(BackButtonAction);

private void BackButtonAction()
{
    ...
}
```

2. `App` does not have a `BindingContext`. Refer to a command on the App object itself.
   Change xaml value to:

```xml
... Value="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:App}}, Path=BackButtonCommand}" ...
```

NOTE: Not tested.

Comment: Hi Steve, I like what you're doing it seems very direct, and I _am_ trying to test it but not having any luck getting that command to fire.  I'm wondering if this relative source `RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:App}` holds up even when the custom NavigationHeader is consumed in the `xaml` of a `ContentPage` (because that's the context in which the Style resource will be referenced). I might be doing something else wrong but I'm very interested in the right answer for this question :)

Comment: Yeah, there might be some subtle issue here. If you *do* get something working, go ahead and write the working version as your own answer. I don't have time to mess with this today.

Comment: Another possible approach: If every page is given property `x:Name="thePage"` in its header, and inherits from `BasePage : ContentPage`, *maybe* `{Binding Source=(x:Reference thePage}, Path=BackButtonCommand}"` *might* be able to find `BackButtonCommand`, if it is put in `BasePage`.